# Extracting items in list to separate dateframes Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
#filter report for a list of manufacturers
manu_list = ['ford','chrysler','mercury','jeep','dodge','ferrari']
df_subset = df[df['manufacturer'].isin(manu_list)]
```

I am working through a problem and am trying to extract items in a list to a separate data frame. As noted above, I was able to create a subset of a dataframe based on rows matching values in a given column. Now, I am trying to create a separate dataframe for each of the values in the list. I came up with the below for loop and am coming up with an error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str'. What am I doing wrong here?

```
for i in manu_list:
     manu_list[i] = vehicles[vehicles['manufacturer'] == i]
```

Edit: So I updated my code as so but not I am trying to call the data frame and being told it isn't defined.

```
for i in range(len(manu_list)):
manu_list[i] = vehicles[vehicles['manufacturer'] == i]
```

Comment: This `manu_list[i]` is what you do wrong. `manu_list` is a list, you cannot index it with a string `i`. Instead, do `manu_dict = {}` and later if the `for` loop: `manu_dict[i] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can just using `groupby`

```
df_subset = df[df['manufacturer'].isin(manu_list)]
l = [ y for x , y in df_subset.groupby('manufacturer')]
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` in manu_list gives you elements in the list, not indexes.

Edit the cycle as `for i in len(manu_list)`.

Answer (score 0):

manu_list is a list, but when you set it up you want it to be a dictionary like so:

```
manu_list={'ford': [], 'jeep': [] ...}
```

Then you can do

```
for i in manu_list:
    manu_list[i].append(vehicles[vehicles['manufacturer'] == i])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try

`for i in manu_list: 
print(i)`

you will notice that it will print every list item as string. Not their indexes.
So you get an error. Because there is no `manu_list['ford']`

instead use:

```
for i in range(len(manu_list)):
print(manu_list[i])
```

and so on

Comment: I'm probably making this more common than i have to im trying to name the dataframes with the manu_list[i] statement. The vehicles[vehicles['manufacturer'] == i] is my statement to select all rows with the manufacturer noted in the list. so the output would be a dataframe with all rows matching foreach entry in the list named something different.

Comment: Ok i think were getting near. You want some new filtered Lists (manu_list[i]) filled with your vehicle_manufacturers? In your case it seems that you want to overwrite your manu_list with your not visible vehicle_dataframe. Can you edit your post with your vehicle dataframe? At least an excerpt

Comment: I apologize. I am probably not being clear enough. The first set of my code correctly outputs the dataframe containing all of the records matching one of the manufacturers. What I am trying to do is take that same list, and instead of outputting one dataframe, it outputs a separate dataframe for each manufacturer in the list. the manu_list[i] statement is just my attempt at a naming convention for the dataframes. This doesn't have to be the name, just trying to figure out what to do with that.